# How to replace any combination of given html tags, whitespaces and newlines with preg_replace?

Tags: php, regex, string, replace, preg-replace

I'm using the following regex syntax in PHP in order to replace empty `<p>`, `<span>` and `<div>` tags, with whichever attributes and spanning any number of *spaces* or *linebreaks*, by something else:

```
$replacement = '\n&nbsp;\n';
$str = preg_replace('/<(p|span|div)\b[^>]*>(\n|[ ]|)+<\/(p|span|div)>/i', $replacement, $source);
```

This is mostly working, but not quite like I'd like it to. Given nested empty elements, it'll only match the inner element. Like in the following source string:

```
$source = '<p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;"></span></p>';
```

The result is going to be:

> ```
> <p class="MsoNormal">
> &nbsp;
> </p>
> ```

I'd like to replace **all** nested elements (any given combination of empty `<p>`, `<span>`and `<div> tags,` plus any number of `whitespaces` and `linebreaks`) by a single copy of `$replacement`. **In other words, I'd like my *regex* to match the source string entirely.**

---

Examples of strings which should be replaced:

```
<div><span class="x"><p></p></span></div>

<span class="x"> <p>  </p></span>    // contains spaces

<p class="y"></p>

<p class="y">    // contains linebreak
</p>
```

Example of strings which should *not* be replaced:

```
<div><span class="z"><p>can't touch this</p></span></div>    // not empty
```

---

How can it be done?

---

**Update:** I managed to write this

```
(?:<(?:p|span|div)\b[^>]*>)+(?:\n|[ ]|)+(?:<\/(p|span|div)>)+
```

It is correctly matching this...

> ```
> <p class="MsoNormal"><span style="font-size: 12pt; font-family: Arial, sans-serif;">  
>
>   </span></p>
> ```

However, it is also "incorrectly" matching the second line from the following:

> ```
> <p class="MsoNormal">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet...
> <span style="font-size: 7.5pt; font-family: Verdana, sans-serif;"></span></p> // this line
> ```

It should *not* match the trailing `</p>` unless the entire `<p>` element was "empty" (no real content). However, it does. Is there a way to tell it not to?

Comment: Have you looked at using a parser?

Comment: @chris85 I tried, but in this case everything indicates I must write this myself. You can see I asked about it previously [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/41619637/3258851).

Comment: You should definitely be using a parser (like noted in the answer of your other question). If you really want to avoid this, the easiest way is, to only match the innermost elements (e.g. the `<p>` tag in `<div><p></p></div>` and replace it with `&nbsp;` while also allowing `&nbsp;` to be in the matching group of your regex. This allows you to repeatedly replace all the matches. If you want to create a recursive expression, it will be very complicated, if not impossible with just using regex (without the recursive extension)